# Guru.com scraper

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape all jobs from `Guru.com (http://www.guru.com/pro/search.aspx?#&&page=1&budget=1000-30000&cid=800&sort=PostedDateDescending)`. If you study this link you will notice that it is doing ajax request to fetch jobs list and just fills dummy html on load. It is an ASP.NET server and I m trying to mimick this ajax request to fetch jobs list. Here is my code

```
$file_contents = parent::fetchPage($url);
        $string = tidy_repair_string($file_contents);
        $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmldoc->loadHTML($string);
        $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
        
        $titleResult = $xpathvar->query('//input[@name="__VIEWSTATE"]');
        $postvars = 'ctl00%24scriptMgr=ctl00%24scriptMgr%7Cctl00%24scriptMgr&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24scriptMgr&__EVENTARGUMENT=page%3D1%26budget%3D1000-30000%26cid%3D800%26sort%3DPostedDateDescending&ctl00_scriptMgr_HiddenField=&__LASTFOCUS=&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSearchId=&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlBudgetMin=0&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlBudgetMax=0&ctl00%24procnt%24Location=rbworldwide&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlCountries=Select%20One&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlCities=Select%20One&ctl00%24procnt%24txtKeyWords=Keywords%20or%20Project%20ID&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnKeyWords=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnSrc=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnPageNo=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnSearchResults=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnProjectID=&ctl00%24procnt%24txtSearchName=&ctl00%24procnt%24txtSearchName_reqd=true&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSelectedTab=0&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSelectSvdSearch=&ctl00%24hdnGuid=GUID&__ASYNCPOST=true&';
        $postvars .= '__VIEWSTATE='.urlencode($titleResult->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('value')->textContent);
        parse_str($postvars, $query);
        
        print_r($query);
        
        $ch = curl_init("http://www.guru.com/pro/search.aspx");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,1);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.guru.com',
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
            'Accept: text/plain, text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            'Referer: http://www.guru.com/pro/search.aspx?',
            'Content-Length: 15818',
            'Pragma: no-cache'
        ));
        echo $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
        $Rec_Data = gzinflate(substr($Rec_Data, 10, -8));
        echo $Rec_Data;
```

I am sending same headers as I see them on Live HTTP Headers firefox plugin which is sent for ajax request. I am receiving following response headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=eip5l545vkyk3aqhq5kliijj; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 21:28:57 GMT
Content-Length: 44051
```

whereas response header that I see on Live HTTP Headers plugin received when ajax done by guru.com is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=bnlurvq3crot1r55juykpt3y; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 19:25:19 GMT
Content-Length: 43290
```

Guru.com is receiving jobs list whereas I am receiving dummy html which does not contain any job. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code. Following is the request headers sent by Guru.com to its server for ajax call.

```
POST /pro/search.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.guru.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://www.guru.com/pro/search.aspx?
Content-Length: 15818
Pragma: no-cache
ctl00%24scriptMgr=ctl00%24scriptMgr%7Cctl00%24scriptMgr&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24scriptMgr&__EVENTARGUMENT=page%3D1%26budget%3D1000-30000%26cid%3D800%26sort%3DPostedDateDescending&ctl00_scriptMgr_HiddenField=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%3D%3D&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSearchId=&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlBudgetMin=0&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlBudgetMax=0&ctl00%24procnt%24Location=rbworldwide&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlCountries=Select%20One&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlCities=Select%20One&ctl00%24procnt%24txtKeyWords=Keywords%20or%20Project%20ID&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnKeyWords=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnSrc=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnPageNo=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnSearchResults=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnProjectID=&ctl00%24procnt%24txtSearchName=&ctl00%24procnt%24txtSearchName_reqd=true&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSelectedTab=0&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSelectSvdSearch=&ctl00%24hdnGuid=GUID&__ASYNCPOST=true&
```

This is the screenshot of the response that I receive.

[image]

Comment: My guess is they are doing it that way to stop people like you from doing what you're doing. Figure it out on your own

Comment: but HTTP is blind. How do they know who is doing that? Also I think there is some issue in my code thats why dummy html response is coming

Comment: maybe there loading the content in via ajax

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

They apparently use JavaScript either as required functionality to render the page, or to protect against bots.  The HTTP client you are providing will have to be able to interpret JavaScript as well.

**Original Reply**

You are sending a different ASP.Net session cookie with each request.

Presumably Guru.com checks for a valid, authenticated session before returning data.

You would have to first programatically log in to the website and obtain a valid session ID, then use that ID in subsequent Ajax requests.

Comment: I have disabled cookies and guru is still responding correctly for their own site but not to the scrapper.

Comment: try disabling javascript as well.

Comment: Also I am not logging in to site when i visit it via browser and the response is coming correctly.

Comment: @Ayeshk then it only loads dummy html for browser as well

Comment: @AyazAlavi: Apparently they are using JavaScript either for required functionality, or to help protect the page from bots.  When I download the page with .NET WebClient, I get **A system error has occurred.** in the body of the HTML.

Comment: Ajax request and response that I see in firebug is not actually what I am getting. Javascript is clientside so it is not the issue. I am not receiving the same response as received by web browser but my request is same. Thats strange. And I am also receiving HTTP/1.1 100 Continue response as you can see in the response headers that I receive which is not received when done ajax request by browser

Answer (score -2):

The site in question was keeping track of position of POST variables. I just rearranged it according to firebug (or Live Http Headers) and bang bang Here comes the data. My final code is (check out the $postvars variable)

```
$file_contents = parent::fetchPage($url);
        $string = tidy_repair_string($file_contents);
        $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmldoc->loadHTML($string);
        $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

        $titleResult = $xpathvar->query('//input[@name="__VIEWSTATE"]');
        $postvars = 'ctl00%24scriptMgr=ctl00%24scriptMgr%7Cctl00%24scriptMgr&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24scriptMgr&__EVENTARGUMENT=page%3D1%26budget%3D1000-30000%26cid%3D800%26sort%3DPostedDateDescending&ctl00_scriptMgr_HiddenField=&__LASTFOCUS=&'.'__VIEWSTATE='.urlencode($titleResult->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('value')->textContent)."&".'ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSearchId=&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlBudgetMin=0&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlBudgetMax=0&ctl00%24procnt%24Location=rbworldwide&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlCountries=Select%20One&ctl00%24procnt%24ddlCities=Select%20One&ctl00%24procnt%24txtKeyWords=Keywords%20or%20Project%20ID&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnKeyWords=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnSrc=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnPageNo=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnSearchResults=&ctl00%24procnt%24ucLeadResults%24hdnProjectID=&ctl00%24procnt%24txtSearchName=&ctl00%24procnt%24txtSearchName_reqd=true&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSelectedTab=0&ctl00%24procnt%24hdnSelectSvdSearch=&ctl00%24hdnGuid=GUID&__ASYNCPOST=true&';
        parse_str($postvars, $query);

        print_r($query);

        $ch = curl_init("http://www.guru.com/pro/search.aspx");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$postvars);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');         
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.guru.com',
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
            'Accept: text/plain, text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            'Referer: http://www.guru.com/pro/search.aspx?',
            'Content-Length: 15818',
        ));
        echo $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
        $Rec_Data = gzinflate(substr($Rec_Data, 10, -8));
```